# Decode error - output not utf-8

Tags: python, sublimetext2

If I try to have Python print the string `"«»••"`, it instead returns

`[Decode error - output not utf-8]`.

How can I fix this? I'm using Sublime Text 2, if it helps.

EDIT: Apparently,

```
print("«»••")
```

works, but not

```
print("Hello world!   «»••")
```

Note that I'm using this at the top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

EDIT x2:

```
repr("Hello world!   «»••")
```

returns

```
'Hello world!   \xc2\xab\xc2\xbb\xe2\x80\xa2\xe2\x80\xa2'
```

Comment: Please share your exact code, not just the output you are trying to produce.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details like that. SublimeText2 uses Python 2 so you are trying to print arbitrary bytes and we don't know where you copied those characters from or what encoding they are using.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the original question with the information.

Comment: There is no difference between the two `print` statements; both write raw bytestrings to `sys.stdout` and it depends on the exact bytes used. Try `print repr(<the string of choice>)` to show what is in the string.

Comment: Updated the OP again. Not sure what to do with this information.

Comment: Well, it shows that your string contains UTF-8 data at least. C2 AB is the UTF-8 encoding for the U+00AB codepoint.

Comment: Ok. So what can I do now to remove the error?

Comment: But what are you trying to do? How much do you know about Python and Unicode? Perhaps reading you should start with reading http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html here.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this will solve your problem or not but if I try formatting:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
print("Hello world!    %s" %"«»••")
```

I'm able to produce the output that isn't working for you.

Nothing shows up however if they are both contained in the same string. Same error if I try to concatenate the strings as well.